# How to read PDF file through iText and display it as in Adobe Reader?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I use `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader` and `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor`
package, and tried:

```
String pagedata=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,pageno)
```

and put the pagedata into a JTextArea.

But by doing this it skips all the images and font sizes and colors and shows only same-sized text data.

I want to fetch all full fledged page by page data as in Adobe Reader. How can I do this and in which component should I place the fetched page? Obviously not on JTextArea...

Comment: `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage` does just what its name says, it *extracts the text from one page,* dropping all non-textual and text style information. iText currently does not contain code to graphically render PDFs.

Comment: then how can i solve my problem??

Comment: For example jPedal is a library which allows PDF viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Desktop class to call Adobe Reader.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file.pdf);
// where file.pdf is your file instance.
```